# How to make 4 Digit Code field like this?

Tags: javascript, html

Here is what I did:

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><input class="clock" type="text" maxlength="1" size="1" onkeyup="next(2)"></td>
    <td><input id="2" class="clock" type="text" maxlength="1" size="1" onkeyup="next(3)"></td>
    <td><input id="3" class="clock" type="text" maxlength="1" size="1" onkeyup="next(4)"></td>
    <td><input id="4" class="clock" type="text" maxlength="1" size="1"></td>
  </tr>
</table>

<script>
  function next(next) {
    document.getElementById(next).focus();
  }
</script>
```

But it skips digits. (here are demos: https://codepen.io/snnirmk/pen/LYyXrMj **and** https://codepen.io/snnirmk/pen/poPQKGo)

How can I make it without skipping digits?

update: first demo didn't work for me but I discovered a new event "oninput" which doesn't make any problems, thanks anyways.

Comment: First demo works for me

Comment: First demo works for me too.. but if you delete the number from say, 3rd input by pressing backspace, it still jumps to the next input. Maybe you can add a check for which button is pressed and skip the jump for certain buttons like backspace and delete.

Comment: Generally, this kind of fancy overriding of default behaviours isn’t a good idea. I recommend a single input, so you don’t break features people rely on (have you thought about paste? speech to text?). If you really want a special look, maybe you can use a monospaced font and style it with `letter-spacing`, then apply a visual mask (still kind of questionable) or some placeholder underlines.

Answer (score 0):

It will skip digits if you press a key down and then press another key down before releasing the previous key (which happens if you type fast).

A quick fix is to do something like this:

```
<table> 
    <tr> 
        <td><input class="clock" type="text" maxlength="1" size="1" onkeydown="next(2)"></td> 
        <td><input id="2" class="clock" type="text" maxlength="1" size="1" onkeydown="next(3)"></td> 
        <td><input id="3" class="clock" type="text" maxlength="1" size="1" onkeydown="next(4)"></td> 
        <td><input id="4" class="clock" type="text" maxlength="1" size="1"></td> 
    </tr>
</table>

<script>function next(next) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        document.getElementById(next).focus(); 
    }, 1);
}</script>
```

This solution is a bit hacky though because it uses the setTimeout function. Ideally it should not use setTimeout function but then the solution would be more complex.